# Titanium.Media.VideoPlayer - How to advance by frame?

Tags: javascript, ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

**Updating this question because I'm building the View in Alloy, not in Titanium**

I'm making this iPhone app and I want to be able to advance a 240fps video frame by frame. [The : documentation for VideoPlayer](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.VideoPlayer) is very helpful but it is only getting me so far, unfortunately. Frame advance does not seem to actually advance, and when I show in the debug log the microsecond calculations, it appears the `currentPlaybackTime` property goes back after it gets set.

Here's the Alloy:

```
<Alloy>
  <Window title="Player" id="vidPlayerWindow">
    <View class="container" id="view">
      <VideoPlayer id="theVideoPlayer" autoplay="false" />
      <View id="controlPanel">
        <Button id="btnPlay" />
        <Button id="btnFrameAdvance" />
      </View>
    </View>
  </Window>
</Alloy>
```

And here's partial Titanium

```
var frameRate = 240.0; // frames per second
var msPerFrame = 1000.00 / frameRate; // how many MS per frame

Ti.API.debug ("Frame advance psuedo-code style string " + msPerFrame + "ms");

$.btnFrameAdvance.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var currentTime = $.theVideoPlayer.getCurrentPlaybackTime();
    var numberOfFrames = 1; // I actually have code to advance by one or ten frames.
    var newTime = currentTime + (numberOfFrames * msPerFrame);
    Ti.API.debug('current Time ' + currentTime + 'ms to new time ' + newTime + 'ms');
    $.theVideoPlayer.setCurrentPlaybackTime(newTime);
});

// (In a similar function, I change `numberOfFrames` to -1 and it reverses a frame instead of advances.)
```

Theoretically, this should all work fine, except when I try this out - well, here's what that debug log shows

```
[DEBUG] Frame should advance by 4.166666666666667ms each press
```

I hit play and then about a second later hit pause. Then I hit the *advance* button.

```
[DEBUG] current Time 1181.8333333333333ms to new time 1186ms
[DEBUG] current Time 1061.6666666666667ms to new time 1065.8333333333335ms
[DEBUG] current Time 1065ms to new time 1069.1666666666667ms
[DEBUG] current Time 1061.6666666666667ms to new time 1065.8333333333335ms
[DEBUG] current Time 1065ms to new time 1069.1666666666667ms
[DEBUG] current Time 1061.6666666666667ms to new time 1065.8333333333335ms
```

Why is the darn thing unable to stay at 1186ms and advance from there? Why does it insist on going all the way back to 1061ms, and then just sort of toggle between 1061ms and 1065ms? So many questions. But I hope you can help me.

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. Thanks for that! Could you check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, please create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: Would you call this a Titanium bug, an Alloy bug, or something else? Where should I look and then where should I file it? Does the above meet the requirements? I think this code is good to reproduce the issue already; you just need to link your own video.

Comment: Alloy is simply a transpiler on top of Titanium so this is definitely a Titanium bug, although it might also be a limitation of the Android APIs we're wrapping. In any case, please create a [JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/) ticket in the AC project and include the above test case.

Comment: iOS issue. I"ll open it.

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator it won't let me create a TIMOB ticket. It's AC-3478; you'll have to move it , I suppose.

Comment: That's perfect. The AC (Appcelerator - INBOX) is where all new tickets go. We move them to the correct project once triaged. Also see http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/03/contributing-to-appcelerator-products/